# Scrollable Screen - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make my Main Screen fully scrollable, I've tried adding a `SingleChildScrowView`, a `Column`, wrap inside a `ListView`, but every single time there's some widget that throws an error or simply disappears, `RenderFlex` issues and etc. How could I make my screen scrollable, like a normal website?

Edit: My code is actually too big, but the body of my Scaffold is essentially like this:

```
Scaffold(
 body: SafeArea(
  child: Column(
   children: <Widget>[
    Container(
     child: ....
    ),
    Expanded(
     child: ....
    ),
   ]
  )
 )
);
```

Comment: Can you please show your code? Show what you have done.

Comment: Wrap the column inside the listview.. And if you are using listview or grid view as child's add "shrink wrap=true"..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make a scrollable view then take  a `ListView` Widget as Parent Widget and if you want to make some widgets with expanded vertically then use Column inside `ListView` or if you want to make `Expanded` in horizontal then take a `Row` widget see the code below and update accordingly as per your requirement, Hope the solution below helps you.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: ListView(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        child: SizedBox(height: 400.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.indigo,
                        child: SizedBox(height: 400.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        child: SizedBox(height: 400.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.indigo,
                        child: SizedBox(height: 400.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        child: SizedBox(height: 400.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)
                    ),
                    Container(
                        color: Colors.indigo,
                        child: SizedBox(height: 400.0, width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,)
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )

      )
    );
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is using  *ListView* or *SingleChildScrollView* like so:

```
 Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(),
        )
      ]),
    ));
```

Or a *ListView*

```
 Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
      child: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[

      ],),
    ));
```